# project update doesn’t activate on client side javascript changes

Tags: meteor

I've just had to reinstall Windows on my computer and in the process reinstall Meteor (the most current version).

I copied across all of the client/server/package files from an archived version of my project and it's running fine for the most part except the project only auto updates when I make changes to html or css files (and it does so very quickly!) When I edit the javascript files it not only doesn't auto update but it ignores my changes even when I manually refresh the page. I have to stop the project and then start it again to see those changes. Also worth noting that server side javascript changes activate an update immediately, this is exclusively on the client side.

Any thoughts? I don't even know where to begin with debugging this

Comment: i've not seen this behavior, but i'd first try a meteor reset. you can backup your db and restore after if losing your data is inconvenient.

Comment: I will do that if I can't find another solution, the thing is that I only just installed Windows and Meteor so this is as clean of an install as it could have been. If versions had lapsed over months of usage then this wouldn't be as confusing...

Comment: You might want to try running meteor with a specific release, for example do `meteor --release 1.3.5.1` and if that fixes things, make the change in `.meteor/release`

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about that feature. I'll get around to this next week and let you know the results